# Export React component to window as a global variable

Tags: reactjs

While developing a new component that needs to do a lot of stuff with refs, I often find myself needing to test component instance methods and trigger state changes, etc. So I often end up needing to add a `window.myComponent = this;` at the end of my constructor while I am developing. This is annoying and I've forgotten to remove it before. Is there an alternative way to achieve this with less work and less (albeit temporary) ugliness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official [React Developer Tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) extension can be used to debug component instances:

[image: react devtools]

Selecting a component in a hierarchy automatically assigns component instance to `$r` global, which is available in console.

Comment: Terrific, thank you! I was looking for something like this